# Why can't I remove the member from the list and delete their interest?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Every blogpost has their own members. To become a member, the interest you submit must be accepted. i am trying to build a remove member function whereby if you are a member, you can remove yourself from the list and if you are the blog_post.author, you can remove ANYONE except yourself (because to remove yourself you need to delete the blogpost entirely.

Once you are removed from the member-list, I also want the initial interest they have submitted to be deleted. I have attached my models.py, urls.py, template.html and views.py in this question. First, i am getting no errors, but I'm unsure of why the interest is not deleted and the member is also not removed. Is there anything wrong with my code?

So basically nothing happens and when i press on the remove button, i get redirected to my details page as shown in my last view sentence.

Few possibilities:

1. I queried the slug wrongly in my template
2. my if and or statement in views.py is wrong
3. my try statement in views.py is wrong

models.py

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
 email                  = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
 username               = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)

class BlogPost(models.Model):
 title                  = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
 author                     = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 slug                   = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)
 members    = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, related_name="members")

class Interest(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   blog_post = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class InterestInvite(models.Model):

   ACCEPT = "ACCEPT"
   DECLINE = "DECLINE"
   PENDING = "PENDING"
   STATUS_CHOICES = [
      (ACCEPT, "accept"),
      (DECLINE, "decline"),
      (PENDING, "pending"),

   ]

   interest = models.OneToOneField(Interest, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="interest_invite")   
   status = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=PENDING)
```

views.py

```
class InterestMixin(object):
    model=Interest

class BlogPostMixin(object):
    model=BlogPost

class MemberListView(UserPassesTestMixin, BlogPostMixin, DetailView):
    template_name = "HomeFeed/membersof_yourpost.html"
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        blog_post=self.get_object()
        context['blog_post'] = blog_post
        return context


def remove_member_view(request, slug):
    user = request.user
    blog_post = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, slug=slug)
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_id = request.POST.get("user_id")
        if (user_id == user.pk and blog_post.members.filter(pk=user.pk).exists()) or (blog_post.author == request.user and user.pk != user_id):
            try:
                removee = Account.objects.get(pk=user_id)
                blog_post.members.remove(removee)
                Interest.objects.filter(user=removee, blog_post=blog_post).delete()
            except Account.DoesNotExist:
                pass
    return redirect('HomeFeed:detail', slug=slug)
```

urls.py

```
    path('<user_id>/', account_view, name="view"),
    path("blog/<pk>/<slug>/member-list/", MemberListView.as_view(), name="member_list"),
    path("removemember/<slug>/", remove_member_view, name="remove_member"),
```

members.html

```
    {% for member in object.members.all %}
    {% if member == request.user %}
    <li class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-info btn-sm mt-3 mb-3" href="{% url 'account:view' member.pk %}">This is you</a></li>
    {% else %}
    <li class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mt-3 mb-3" href="{% url 'account:view' member.pk %}">{{member.username}}</a></li>
    {% endif %}

        <form method="POST" action="{% url 'HomeFeed:remove_member' object.slug %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Remove</button>
        </form> 


    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: I don't see anything like `user_id` in your form. How do you expect it to end up in your POST parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not posting any `user_id` to your view. Try this:
In your template:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'HomeFeed:remove_member' object.slug %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="number" name="user_id" value="{{ member.id }}" hidden>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Remove</button>
</form>
```

Also in your view the condition is a bit wrong, change it to:

```
if blog_post.author.id != user_id and blog_post.members.filter(pk=user_id).exists() and (user_id == user.pk or blog_post.author == user)
```

Comment: Hey Abdul thanks! I’ll try this out and get back to you on it :)

Answer (score 1):

Your class `BlogPost` relate `ManyToManyField` with `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` but in your `remove_member_view` function, you query with `Account`.

```py
if (user_id == user.pk and blog_post.members.filter(pk=user.pk).exists()) or (blog_post.author == request.user and user.pk != user_id):
            try:
                removee = Account.objects.get(pk=user_id) #<== here
                blog_post.members.remove(removee)
                Interest.objects.filter(user=removee, blog_post=blog_post).delete()
            except Account.DoesNotExist:
                pass
```

Besides, I can not understand what is the purpose of `user_id`, no `user_id` was shown in html to be sent with `POST` request, which may lead to not execute the `if` condition:

**Update** You can try this:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()

removee= User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
```

And change the `if` statement as Abdul recommended above.

Comment: sure, based on your opinion could you suggest the code for me to learn and edit :)